# C# EF Core Added new function to model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a conceptual question about adding new functions to a ef core model.
Image this code is the ef core model of an Account. Its simplified for this example.

```
public class Account: IAccount
{
   public uint Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }  


    public Account()
    {
        
    }
}
```

How would I add a new function, say SendActivationMail(), which I can call like account.SendActiviationMail(), where the SendActiviationMail itself requires depency injection of another service say "MailService".

```
    public class Account: IAccount
{
   public uint Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }  


    public Account()
    {
        
    }

   SendActivationMail(){
      MailService.Send(xxxx);
   }
}
```

I search a lot to find useful resources online, but the lack of them indicates that I am either not searching for the right term or my appraoch is wrong.

From my understanding, ef core needs the empty constructor to construct the object with data it gets from the db. So i cannot just simply add an new depency.

Is this an antipattern, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not adding any business logic in your database classes. Instead, create a service that will send account activation mails with a signature like this:

```
internal class AccountActivationService : IAccountActivationService
{
    public AccountActivationService(IMailService mailService)
    {
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    public void SendMail(IAccount account)
    {
        // Create message here
        // ...

        this.mailService.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

That way your database classes remain very lightweight, while the functionality is accessible through a stateless service